# Hierarchial dynamic dropdown list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In my firm, I've a database like this and I want to create a hierarchical dynamically updating drop down list.

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
| Institute | Industry | Course |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| a         | aa       | aaa    |
| a         | aa       | bbb    |
| b         | bb       | mmm    |
| b         | cc       | ddd    |
| b         | bb       | ttt    |
| c         | ee       | fff    |
| d         | ee       | ggg    |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I want the end result to be something like this. The user will start from the top. Depending on top entry bottom list will change accordingly. Below is a snapshot.

[My User Entry List Demo Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEN83.png)

**My Approach**

My plan was to create an array formula which indexes the course list based on the first two entry. Then use offset to take the course entries. But my problem is though I am able to index the course list I am not able to sort them to use in data validation. And data validation does not ignore the non-filled or error values, which I don't want. Assuming I solved the first hierarchy problem and I've the Institute and Industry output. I tried this

> G8 - Institute Input from drop down 
>   G9 - Industry Input from drop down 
>   H11:H15 - respective courses

And the formula in H11:H15 is `{=INDEX(C2:C8,1/(1/((A2:A8=G8)*(B2:B8=H8)*(ROW(C2:C8)-1))))}`

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIlTS.png) I'm getting. 

 
I am fairly new to posting questions. Let me know if I can make it more clear.
Also, I found these very useful links while surfing the internet.
Pardon me for adding as code, as SO doesn't allow more than 2 links for new members

```
1: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html
2: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/
```

Comment: What should the Course list be based on the Institute and Industry input? You have duplicate values in the first two lists which are going to add a level of complexity to this. I'm assuming these are made up fake values for illustration purposes?

Comment: There cannot be two same courses for one Institute in one particular industry. You can assume all courses for a institute are unique. But two different institute can contain a same course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to put this formula as an array into H11:H18:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:C8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(C2:C8)-1)/((A2:A8=G8)*(B2:B8=G9)),ROW()-ROW(H10)),1),"")
```

Then you can set your data validation for the course option to H11:H18.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @jacob. I was able to use your formula along with `=OFFSET(H10,1,0,COUNTIF(H11:H18,"*"),1` in Data Validation List formula to dynamize the list. But please explain your formula in a details as I not familiear with ROW() and AGGREGATE function and its use here in this case

Comment: The aggregate function allows you to apply math/trig functions while ignoring errors. We can exploit this in many ways. In this case we use it to find only the rows where A2:A8=G8 & B2:B8=G9. When we divide ROW(C2:C8)-1 by this, any row that does not equal G8 or G9 will be divided by zero, which will cause it to be ignored by the aggregate function.

Comment: The aggregate function now returns an array of all of the row numbers that match these conditions, and then the ROW()-ROW(H10) at the end tells it to pick the smallest matching value, and as we drag it down, this becomes the 2nd smallest, 3rd smallest, and so on. Now we can use Index to find the values in C2:C8 on those matching rows.

Comment: If you found this to be the answer to your question I would appreciate it if you mark the check mark selecting it as the answer. Hope this explanation helps!